# Error: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.at ZstdSharp.Unsafe.Methods.ZSTD_initCCtx after deloyment to Azure

Tags: .net, mongodb, azure

I have a WebAPI service, when I debug it locally everything is working fine but after I deployed it to Azure App Service (Windows) I'm getting the following error when trying to fetch data from Mongo:

`Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.at ZstdSharp.Unsafe.Methods.ZSTD_initCCtx(ZSTD_CCtx_s* cctx, ZSTD_customMem memManager)at ZstdSharp.Unsafe.Methods.ZSTD_createCCtx_advanced(ZSTD_customMem customMem)at ZstdSharp.Unsafe.Methods.ZSTD_createCCtx()at ZstdSharp.Compressor..ctor(Int32 level)at ZstdSharp.CompressionStream..ctor(Stream stream, Int32 level, Int32 bufferSize) MongoDB.Driver.Core.Compression.ZstandardCompressor.Compress(Stream input, Stream output)`

any ideas what can it be?

I tried to uncheck 'Code Optimization'
and also updated all Mongo packages